# Why the state variable cannot update by the context variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code:
The source code of top components (i.e. RosterScheduler.js) as the following:

```
import {Col,Container,Row} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import CalendarUtility from '../../../utils/calendar/CalendarUtility';
import MonthPicker from '../../monthPicker/MonthPicker';
import Roster from '../../../utils/Roster';
import RosterSchedulerTable from '../../tables/rosterSchedulerTable/RosterSchedulerTable';
export default function RosterScheduler(props){
    const [rosterMonth,setRosterMonth]=useState(new Date());
    const[rosterSchedulerData,setRosterSchedulerData]=useState();
    let monthPickerMinDate=props.systemParam.monthPickerMinDate;
    //console.log(monthPickerMinDate);
    monthPickerMinDate=new Date(monthPickerMinDate.year,monthPickerMinDate.month-1,monthPickerMinDate.date);

    //console.log(props);
    //console.log(props.systemParam.monthSelectorMinDate);
    let updateMonth=(year,month)=>{
        //console.log("updateMonth="+year+","+month);
        let newDate=new Date();
        newDate.setFullYear(year);
        newDate.setMonth(month);
        setRosterMonth(newDate);
    }
    let systemParam=props.systemParam;
    useEffect(()=>{
        const getData = async () => {
            let calendarUtility=new CalendarUtility();
            let monthlyCalendar=calendarUtility.getMonthlyCalendar(rosterMonth.getFullYear(),rosterMonth.getMonth());
            let roster = new Roster();
            let rosterData = await roster.getRosterSchedulerList(rosterMonth.getFullYear(),rosterMonth.getMonth()+1);
            let activeShiftInfoList= await roster.getAllActiveShiftInfo();
            setRosterSchedulerData(
               {
                "activeShiftInfoList":activeShiftInfoList,
                "calendarUtility":calendarUtility,
                "monthlyCalendar":monthlyCalendar,
                "rosterData":rosterData,                
                "systemParam":systemParam
               }
            )
        }
        getData();    
    },[rosterMonth]);
    return (
        <div className="App p-1">
            <Container fluid={true} className="tableContainer">
                <Row>
                    <Col className="font-weight-bold text-center tableCaption" md={12} lg={12} sm={12} xl={12} xs={12}>
                        <u>Computer Operation Support Services Team Roster</u>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={12} lg={12} sm={12} xl={12} xs={12}>
                        <MonthPicker 
                            minDate={monthPickerMinDate}
                            onSelect={updateMonth} />
                    </Col>
                </Row>           
                <Row>
                    <Col className="d-flex justify-content-center p-0" md={12} lg={12} sm={12} xl={12} xs={12}>
                        {rosterSchedulerData && <RosterSchedulerTable rosterSchedulerData={rosterSchedulerData}/>}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>        
        </div>
    )    
}
```

The source code of RosterSchedulerTable.js as below:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import RosterWebContext from '../../../RosterWebContext';
import RosterSchedulerTableBody from './rosterSchedulerTableBody/RosterSchedulerTableBody';

export default function RosterSchedulerTable(props){
    
    const [hightLightCellIndex, setHightLightCellIndex] = useState(-1);
    const [rosterData,setRosterData]=useState(props.rosterSchedulerData.rosterData);

    let activeShiftInfoList=props.rosterSchedulerData.activeShiftInfoList;
    let calendarUtility=props.rosterSchedulerData.calendarUtility;
    let monthlyCalendar=props.rosterSchedulerData.monthlyCalendar;
    let systemParam=props.rosterSchedulerData.systemParam;
    
    let contextValue={
        activeShiftInfoList,
        calendarUtility,
        hightLightCellIndex,
        monthlyCalendar,
        rosterData,
        setHightLightCellIndex,
        setRosterData,
        systemParam    
    };
    
    return (
        <table id="rosterTable">
            <RosterWebContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
                <RosterSchedulerTableBody/>
            </RosterWebContext.Provider>
        </table>
    );
}
```

The RosterSchedulerTableBody.js source as the following:

```
import {useContext,useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import RosterSchedulerRow from './RosterSchedulerRow';
import VacantShiftRow from './VacantShiftRow';
export default function RosterSchedulerTableBody(){
    let {rosterData} = useContext(RosterWebContext);
    let rowList = [];
    console.log("data:"+rosterData.rosterList[1].shiftList.length);
    
    return (
        <tbody>            
            {rowList}
        </tbody>
    );
}
```

This is RosterWebContext.js content:

```
import React from 'react'
const RosterWebContext = React.createContext({});
export default RosterWebContext
```

When the page has loaded the content of `rosterData` in both `RosterSchedulerTable` and `RosterSchedulerTableBody` are the same,
however, when the user picks a month from the MonthPicker, the state variable `rosterData` in `RosterSchedulerTable` should be updated, and then it should update the content of `rosterData` in `RosterSchedulerTableBody`, unfortunately, the content of `rosterData` in `RosterSchedulerTableBody` does not update.

Because both roster.getRosterSchedulerList, roster.getAllActiveShiftInfo methods are getting data from a server, so I cannot demonstrate the problem on stackblitz.

Would you tell me how to fix the problem?

Comment: When you say "ancestor component", are you referring specifically to `RosterSchedulerTable`, or are you referring to the source `props.rosterSchedulerData.rosterData`?

Comment: Yes, I refer to the RosterSchedulerTable.

Comment: I asked if you could provide code demonstrating how you update the state variable `rosterData`, because currently that is not shown in your question.

Comment: Sure, I added the code to the question.

Comment: You've gone full-circle. The answer to your original question is the same as the answer to your current question. The only difference is that the `useState()` which is causing the problem is now in `RosterSchedulerTable` rather than `RosterSchedulerTableBody` as you had originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useState(initialState)` is not sensitive to the `initialState` changing on subsequent renders after mounting the component, so `rosterData` will not change when `props.rosterSchedulerData.rosterData` does.

The solution is to [lift your state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) again if you want the state to reflect changes to `rosterSchedulerData.rosterData` in your `RosterScheduler` component.

Comment: do you mean I need to create a state variable for rosterData and then put it in the into RosterWebContext?

Comment: @TheKNVB correct. The provider should provide its own `setRosterData` function as part of the value, like `<RosterWebContext.Provider value={[rosterData, setRosterData]} ...` then you'll change the hook call to `let [rosterData, setRosterData] = useContext(RosterWebContext);`

Comment: I have tried the solution, it does not work. I  updated the code for your reference.

Comment: @TheKNVB maybe you misunderstood me? The point was to remove `const[rosterInfo,setRosterInfo]=useState(rosterData);` and begin using `rosterData` and `setRosterData` directly instead.

Comment: I have updated the code, it still does not work.

Comment: @TheKNVB what is the problem you're experiencing now? "It does not work" is not a problem statement. How are you updating `rosterData`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the update the question, the question content is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I get it working properly.

The source code of RosterSchedulerTable.js as below:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import RosterWebContext from '../../../RosterWebContext';
import RosterSchedulerTableBody from './rosterSchedulerTableBody/RosterSchedulerTableBody';
import TableHeader from '../tableHeader/TableHeader';
export default function RosterSchedulerTable(props){
    
    const [hightLightCellIndex, setHightLightCellIndex] = useState(-1);
    let activeShiftInfoList=props.rosterSchedulerData.activeShiftInfoList;
    let calendarUtility=props.rosterSchedulerData.calendarUtility;
    let monthlyCalendar=props.rosterSchedulerData.monthlyCalendar;
    let rosterData=props.rosterSchedulerData.rosterData;
    let systemParam=props.rosterSchedulerData.systemParam;
    
    useEffect(()=>{
          setRosterData(props.rosterSchedulerData.rosterData);
    },[props.rosterSchedulerData.rosterData])

    let contextValue={
        activeShiftInfoList,
        calendarUtility,
        hightLightCellIndex,
        monthlyCalendar,
        rosterData,
        setHightLightCellIndex,
        systemParam    
    };
    return (
        <table id="rosterTable">
            <RosterWebContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
                <TableHeader noOfPrevDate={systemParam.noOfPrevDate}/>
                <RosterSchedulerTableBody/>
            </RosterWebContext.Provider>
        </table>
    );
}
```

The source code of RosterSchedulerTableBody.js as below:

```
import {useContext,useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import PreferredShiftRow from './PreferredShiftRow';
import RosterSchedulerRow from './RosterSchedulerRow';
import RosterWebContext from '../../../../RosterWebContext';
import VacantShiftRow from './VacantShiftRow';
export default function RosterSchedulerTableBody(){
    const[rosterInfo,setRosterInfo]=useState();
    let {rosterData} = useContext(RosterWebContext);
    
    let rowList = [];
    console.log("info:"+rosterInfo.rosterList[1].shiftList.length);
    console.log("data:"+rosterData.rosterList[1].shiftList.length);
    return (
        <tbody>            
            {rowList}
        </tbody>
    );
}
```

Patrick, thank you